# closing popovers on websites automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I'm using puppeteer on a website that has randomly appearing popovers. They appear rarely, but when they do, the DOM is changed temporarily until the popover is manually closed, which causes my program to crash.

I attempted to fix this by listening for such popovers and simply make puppeteer click on the 'x' button immediately whenever they occur.

I tried it like this:

```
page.on('domcontentloaded', async function() {
    await page.waitForSelector('#popover-x', {
      timeout: 3000
    });
    let closePopoverButton = await page.$('#popover-x');
    if (closePopoverButton != null) { // if the new DOM-content is actually a popover
      await closePopoverButton.click();
    }
  });
```

and like this:

```
page.on('domcontentloaded', async function() {
    await page.waitForSelector('#popover-x', {
      timeout: 3000
    });
    await page.$eval('#popover-x', (element) => {
      element.click();
    });
  });
```

Both result in the X-Button being selected correctly, but the popover doesn't close. Also no errors occur.

(the X-button (`#popover-x`) is not an actual button, but a tiny div that listens for a click-event inside of it)

Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried: 
     await page.click('#popover-x');
which returned an error: "Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions.
First one:

```
await page.waitFor(2000);
```

before the waitForSelector-Part.

Not sure why waitForSelector() doesn't work here, but apperently 2 seconds are enough for everything to load.

But theres an even better solution:

I simply add a style element to the DOM after every page load, which contains css to not display the popover. Here's what it looks like:

```
async function hidePopovers(page){ 
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(()=>{
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = '.popover{display: none !important}'; 
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
      let [head] = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
      head.append(style);
  }, 1000);   
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you define a function which close popup on click of "#popover-x" button

Comment: No, I didn't do that explicitly because such a function most likely already exists, and should get triggered on mouseclick ..

Comment: Firstly confirm that function is defined somewhere or not. if not defined, then you have to define it

Comment: I'm sure it is defined because the popover couldn't be closed at all if there wasn't a function